# How can i custom the scrollbar color in Delphi2009?

Tags: delphi, scrollbar

Sadly that Delphi2009 has applied the theme service and it always draw the scrollbar using the Windows System Theme. As a result, i cannot custom the scrollbar color.

Is it possible that i can custom the scrollbar color without changing the OS System Theme?

Addition:
The Windows Theme is not my concern, i'm only trying to custom the scrollbar color of a given control, such as TMemo, or TStringGrid, etc.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want just to customize the toolbar or you want your application without runtime themes support?

Comment: I've try disable the runtime theme in the project options, but it doesn't help, the scrollbar still themed

Comment: That sounds implausible. If your code worked with an older Delphi that did not support runtime themes, then it should behave just the same in modern Delphi with themes disabled. Perhaps you can show us code that reproduces the problem, and tell us what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @David, after round and round search in Google, i believe that's a system behavior rather than Delphi itself. Seems that Windows API has wrapped this function, and i'm trying to find a way to overwrite it but failed, do you have any idea?

Comment: We don't actually know what your problem is. You have not provided anywhere near enough information. So far as we can tell, disabling themes will allow you to change colour. Please show us some code. Please show us the code you were using in previous versions of Delphi, the code that does what you want.

Comment: @David, sorry for the late reply. I don't need to provide you the sample code, you can just try, disable the runtime theme in project options, and then demo a TMemo without any extra code but just set its property ScrollBar to "ssBoth", you'll find that the scrollbar is still themed

Comment: Such an app is not themed. Because you disabled runtime themes. If you do the same on a vanilla Delphi 6 app (pre XP theme manager) then the app looks identical to the one you have just described. So what exactly has changed? I'd like to see the code that you have that works in old Delphi and that does not work in modern Delphi. Do you have such code? Your question suggests that you do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explict disabling the theming for the memo will work...

```
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TMemo=Class(StdCtrls.TMemo)
    Procedure CreateWnd;override;
  End;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation
uses uxTheme;

{$R *.dfm}



{ TMemo }

procedure TMemo.CreateWnd;
begin
  inherited;
   SetWindowTheme(Handle,'','');
end;

end.
```

Comment: +1 I still can't understand why Leo didn't already have to tackle this with the pre Delphi upgrade app

Comment: Thank you two kindly help, i know SetWindowTheme can disable the Theme, but my goal is to custom the scrollbar's color, is it any way to do that?

Comment: May be this link will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200149/is-it-possible-to-paint-on-scrollbars